# Python - Pandas terminate `read_sql` based on user action

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, performance

We are using pandas [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) for retrieving query results that are triggered by a frontend. Just to simplify use case, assume user gives some parameters (table name, clauses, etc.) that we then convert to sql and then execute it using read_sql. 
After pandas sends result, we send it back to frontend where it's displayed to user. All good till here.

We also give user option to "stop", so when query is taking longer, we "stop" on frontend, and allow user to "query" again.

However, the problem is, we have no way of quitting/terminating this query on the backend.

Is there a way we can cancel execution based on above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

What if you read your data by chunks and use some condition so you can stop the loop when necessary? Would be this valid for you?

```
import pandas as pd

query = 'SELECT...'

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(query, connection, chunksize=10):
    if user_cancel:
        break
    print(chunk)
```

More info in: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html

Comment: It's not an effective solution, because the point is that the user should be able to cancel the query itself in case it takes to long (even before the first fetch).